# Get servername of client curl server

Tags: php, apache, curl

The following script is run on a server who's name is `domain_one.com`.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://domain_two.com/testing/curl2.php');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('x'=>1,'y'=>2,'z'=>3));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

curl2.php is located on `domain_two.com`, and has the following script:

```
echo('<pre>'.print_r($_POST,1).'</pre>');
echo('<pre>'.print_r($_SERVER,1).'</pre>');
```

When I run the first script on `domain_one.com`, I get the following output.

```
Array
(
    [x] => 1
    [y] => 2
    [z] => 3
)

Array
(
    [HTTPS] => on
    [SSL_TLS_SNI] => domain_two.com
    [HTTP_HOST] => domain_two.com
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 319
    [HTTP_EXPECT] => 100-continue
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------ed367d0bca2b
    [PATH] => /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at domain_two.com Port 443

    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
    [SERVER_NAME] => domain_two.com
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 222.222.222.222
    [SERVER_PORT] => 443
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 111.111.111.111
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/domain_two/html
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => root@localhost
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/domain_two/html/testing/curl2.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 43092
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_URI] => /testing/curl2.php
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /testing/curl2.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /testing/curl2.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1421509992.179
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1421509992
)
```

Could the script on `domain_two.com` obtain the servername (i.e. `domain_one.com`) which is accessing it?  I see that I can get the REMOTE_ADDR (i.e. 111.111.111.111) which is associated with `domain_one.com`.

What are the implications if both scripts are accessed as subdomains (i.e. `subdomain.domain_one.com`)?

WHY I AM DOING THIS:
domain_one sends a curl request to domain_two script.  domain_two sets some headers and responds that it received the request, but doesn't quit.  Instead, it does some long process (a minute or so, maybe longer), and when it is finished, needs to do a curl request back to domain_one indicating that it is finished.

Comment: [Reverse DNS lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) ?

Comment: @Himal  I was thinking that might be required.  I added to my original post why I wish to do this.  Maybe there is another way altogether?

Comment: Why not just adding it in the script on domain_one as a post field? Is there something that prohibits you from doing this? Maybe I'm interpreting it wrong...

Comment: @Seirddriezel  No, you are interpreting it correctly, and that is exactly what I was previously doing.  I thought that maybe the same name came over automatically in the request, thus asked this question.

Comment: I see two possible ways to get domain name 1. send additional header from your curl request, 2. send $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] as additional parameter from your curl request.  But both of them seem to be useless if I got your problem right. Do you plan to intantiate new callback from your domain_two? you need some additional information then, user_session_id at least.

Comment: @KimAlexander  Are not your two possible ways the same?  The call back will not apply to the user's session, but update the database, and when the user refreshes the page, it will show the updated values.

Comment: no, these two way are different, headers and body are different things, but in your case we really don't care. and if I got it correct you already had the code that realize this technique. so now I have nothing to add.

Comment: I doubt there is another way. except, of course, what you are currently doing.sending it with the client request.Can you edit the DNS on `domain_one` ? if so, just create a `PTR` record and use [gethostbyaddr](http://php.net/gethostbyaddr) to get the mapped domain.